# 1998 Toyota Pre Runner Will not start?

Tags: toyota, starting, tacoma

Turn the key on all you hear is the relay click, no starter noise.  New battery and new starter are on it.  What could it be?  Is there a neutral safety switch?

Comment: If an auto, there should be a neutral safety switch, but if you've recently put the starter on, I'd check your connections at the solenoid. Could be either the solenoid energizer wire or the main battery lead not being connected cleanly. Worth a double check.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure you are in Park and the car knows it. I've had this happen to one of my vehicles where the shifter would be in Park, but the car wouldn't see that it's in Park because the shifter was "wobbly" when in Park. The shifter was clicked into the Park position, but it could still move around a little bit and stay in Park. For my vehicle, I need to give the shifter a little tap forward to make sure the car sees that it's in Park.
2. Try Neutral. Move your shifter around, sometimes the car just can't see where the shifter is.
3. Check your battery voltage using a multimeter ($15 at WalMart), should be 11.8V at an absolute minimum, 12.4-12.6V is preferred.

Answer (score 1):

The click must be a started solenoid, don't think you'd hear a relay solenoid. So it means it is in neutral, and a ECU knows it, and electricity goes to starter solenoid. Only doesn't get to a motor, unless motor end gear is stopping against a flywheel tooth. 
 If your lights on the dash becomes dark or disappears at starting moment, it means you have not enough electricity to turn over the starter motor (battery issue). If it just clicks, and lights looks okay, it means solenoid doesn't move the core as far as it should (stops against the flywheel). In this case you can try to stick it in 4 - 5 gear and turn over the crank. Just a bit, 1 degree is enough :)

Comment: It is not the solenoid, I pulled the power relay and the clicking stopped.  Replaced it and the clicking came back, but no noise from the starter area.